# how to get single value from input name field instead of array in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to delete elements from the note list. when I try to match a single name to a list title, it shows an array of items.
i want to match

const input name ===day
and output should be "home" from input name field
but it show ["home","home","home","home"]

here is my delete form code:

```
 <form action="/delete" method="POST">
 <% for (let i=0; i<newListItems.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="item">

        <input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" name="checkboxname" value="<%=newListItems[i]._id%>">
        <p><%=  newListItems[i].name  %></p>
         
      </div>
      <input type="hidden"  name="listName" value="<%= listTitle %>"></input>
      <% } %>
    </form>
```

app.js code:

```
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
  const deleteItem = req.body.checkboxname
  const listName = req.body.listName
  console.log(listName)


  if (listName === day) {
    console.log("hello")
  } else {
    console.log("custome list value")
  }
  
    

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 4 hidden inputs rendered with same name `listName`.

So your request payload will be fulfilled with array of values from all of these inputs.

Move hidden input outside of PHP loop.
The point is to make one input with `name='listName'` instead of four